# horizontal UNION ALL

Tags: join, sqlite, union-all

I have two tables and I need to select one column from each of them.
This must be done in a single query.
The good news is that the two columns are ordered the right way and they both contain the same number of rows.
Now, I know I could JOIN the two tables by rowid, but it is slow as it has to do that comparison. In my case it is not necessary... I need something more like horizontal UNION ALL to concatenate two columns of equal length.

Is anything like that possible in SQLite 3?

Thanks.

**TABLE1:**

```
| timestamp | FIELD1 | FIELD2 | ...
| 12345678  | 000000 | 000000 | ...
| 00154789  | 000000 | 000000 | ...
```

**TABLE2:**

```
| temperature |
| 1000000000  |
| 2000000000  |
```

**REQUIRED SELECT OUTPUT**

```
| timestamp | temperature |
| 12345678  | 1000000000  |
| 00154789  | 2000000000  |
```

**QUERY**:

```
SELECT timestamp, temperature
FROM TABLE1 INNER JOIN TABLE2 ON TABLE1.rowid = TABLE2.rowid;
```

This takes ~0.75s in my testing app. When I do two separate SELECTs and join the outputs later in my program it takes ~0.4s, but it is not very convenient. The fastest way (~0.23s) is to have both columns in one table, but it is wasteful as I have multiple versions of TABLE2 that share the same timestamps.

Comment: @mu is too short By horizontal I mean "next to each other" rather than "on the top of each other". I need two short columns in the result set rather than one long...

Comment: That sounds exactly like a standard join and proper indexing should make that fast.

Comment: @mu is too short rowid should be always indexed, but it is still way slower (50%) than two separate SELECTs.

Answer (score 0):

[SQLite supports `UNION ALL`](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_select.html#compound).

> Two or more simple SELECT statements
>   may be connected together to form a
>   compound SELECT using the UNION, UNION
>   ALL, INTERSECT or EXCEPT operator. In
>   a compound SELECT, all the constituent
>   SELECTs must return the same number of
>   result columns. As the components of a
>   compound SELECT must be simple SELECT
>   statements, they may not contain ORDER
>   BY or LIMIT clauses. ORDER BY and
>   LIMIT clauses may only occur at the
>   end of the entire compound SELECT.
>
> A compound SELECT created using UNION
>   ALL operator returns all the rows from
>   the SELECT to the left of the UNION
>   ALL operator, and all the rows from
>   the SELECT to the right of it. The
>   UNION operator works the same way as
>   UNION ALL, except that duplicate rows
>   are removed from the final result set.
>   The INTERSECT operator returns the
>   intersection of the results of the
>   left and right SELECTs. The EXCEPT
>   operator returns the subset of rows
>   returned by the left SELECT that are
>   not also returned by the right-hand
>   SELECT. Duplicate rows are removed
>   from the results of INTERSECT and
>   EXCEPT operators before the result set
>   is returned.